# Having trouble running React JS on Mac. 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx

I am new to React and trying to run a simple code in React on Mac, but could not run successfully the code. I got the following errors:

This explains in detail the error:

> 6 | React.DOM.render(

> react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.DOM.render(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED>*MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(*App__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2**["default">], null), document.getElementById('root'));

Here is the code and files:

package.json

```
    {
       "name": "a",
       "version": "0.1.0",
       "private": true,
       "dependencies": {
       "react": "^16.8.6",
       "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
       "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
    },
      "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
       "extends": "react-app"
     },
    "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
     "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version"
      ]
     }
    }
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.expprts = {
    bundle: './src/index.js
}
```

index.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import HelloWorld from './App';

 React.DOM.render(
    React.createElement(HelloWorld, null),
    document.getElementById('root')
 )
```

App.js

```
 import React from 'react';

 let h1 = React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello World')

 class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return React.createElement('div', null, h1, h1)
 }

}

export default HelloWorld;
```

Comment: I think you have a typo: React.DOM.render(...), it should be ReactDOM.render(...) (without the "." between "React" and "DOM")

Comment: ReactDOM.render not React.DOM.render

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(HelloWorld, null),
    document.getElementById('root')
 )
```

you should use

ReactDOM.render()